# Making bootable HDD with Ubuntu setup

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Is there a way to make a bootable HDD with Ubuntu setup from Windows?

Basically I want to make the same thing as a bootable USB stick, only on HDD. This might sound a little bit useless, but I don't have any other way to boot up my other machine and any preinstalled OS fails to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Specify Type as "Hard Disk" and then for Drive specify your drive letter (C:\, D:\, E:\, etc).

Make sure you select your .iso image in the Diskimage section.